# App in the system_process using emulator on windows only

Tags: android, process, android-emulator, system

android:process ="system_process"
android:sharedUserId = "android.uid.system"

in the manifest , but still i am getting a strange error on the emulator console i.e.
 Installation error: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED

if any of you have launched an app in the system_process please lemme know.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Look at the log to see the error.

That said...  seriously...  DON'T run apps in the system process.  Just don't.